# Bootstrap dropdown won't work In Node app because of jQuery

Tags: jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, web, handlebars.js

I am currently creating a node app using handlebars. For the layout, I want a Bootstrap navbar with a dropdown inside of it. The dropdown will not work because I cannot get jquery to work.

Here is my directory structure only including relevant files:

```
root
  ├ models
  ├ node_modules
  | ├ jquery
  ├ public
  | ├ css
  | | ├ bootstrap.css
  | ├ fonts
  | ├ js
  | | ├ bootstrap.js
  | | ├ jquery-3.1.1.js  
  ├ routes
  ├ views
  ├ app.js  
  ├ package.json
```

As you can see, I've downloaded jquery as a module and have also added it into my public folder using the downloaded version from the website.

I've linked it on my layout.handlebars file like so:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
```

I've also required it in my app.js file like so:

```
var $ = require('jQuery');
```

Even with two methods of implementation, jQuery is still not working and is causing my dropdown to not work.

If I inspect my page, I get this message:
[image]
If I check sources, we can see my bootstrap js file and the jquery file linked, though:
[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That errors tells you the problem. You have jquery 3.1.1 but bootstrap requires a version of jquery less than 3.

Comment: Oh my god.. thanks.. I was using an ancient version of bootstrap. I feel like quitting coding now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After actually using my brain and reading, the error message tell me my version of Bootstrap was incompatible with my version of jQuery. See the error message in my question above for clarification.

Comment: "kiddo"? How is your answer in any way or shape a complete answer? If another user with the same question as you came in and saw that answer (which is actually pretty much what the error says), do you think they would have any idea what this means? A real answer would have at least a little more substance.

Comment: Your question on the other hand is exemplary; well formatted, had relevant code, and gave out all of the detail needed to find out what was going on. Answers should be of a similar caliber :)